# imageview is not displayed in jellybean with match_parent

Tags: android

In the given layout the imageview is not being displayed in jellybean devices.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/opLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/id3_kb_op">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="161px"
         android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"

        android:src="@drawable/id3_op_bar"
    />
```

Comment: Then try using "fill_parent"

Comment: what if you give height also as match_parent? Is it showing image then? fill_parent is anyway deprecated. so dont try it..

Comment: An advice...  Never use px in layouts use dp..

Comment: Arshad Parwez fill_parent also not working

Comment: Sushil i can not give height as match_parent height of image view is not exactly as its parent

Comment: Maybe keeping fixed size is causing problem for you as your image may be maintaining aspect ratio. bdw is it working on iCS or below??

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your layout ? Is it displayed in other devices ?

Comment: I suggest you to add another sub-layout inside your RelativeLayout and inside this layout, add your ImageView tag. Also give the height in dp or dip instead of px.

Comment: Sushil its not working on ICS even. but if i give imagewidth as 1280px then image is displayed in all devices but with 1 px margin from both the sides

Answer (score 0):

Then try something like this :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

And also if there is any padding into parent view then please remove that

Comment: Harish Godara .. this image has width of 1280px .Initially instead of match_parent i gave 1280 widht but then there is 1 px gap from both the sides and image is displaying

Comment: Im testing on 1280px width device.

Comment: Image was displaying with same height as you saying above? Means at that point of time when image was displaying height was same as it now?

Comment: Its height is increased. its 171px

Comment: I have edited my comment please check that and avoid using **px**, just use **dip**